# How to convert bytes to uint in Solidity

Tags: solidity, bytes, assembly

Hey is there a way to convert `bytes` to `uint` in Solidity?

Comment: Could you explain what conversion you would like? Best if you can give an example of a `bytes` value and the corresponding `uint` value you would like to see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this function to convert `bytes` to `uint`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract mycontract {

    function bytesToUint(bytes b) public returns (uint256){
        uint256 number;
        for(uint i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            number = number + uint(b[i])*(2**(8*(b.length-(i+1))));
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Updated function for `solidity ^0.8.11`

```
function bytesToUint(bytes memory b) internal pure returns (uint256){
        uint256 number;
        for(uint i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            number = number + uint(uint8(b[i]))*(2**(8*(b.length-(i+1))));
        }
    return number;
}
```

The amount of gas used depends on the length of your `bytes` variable, but this is cheap. Converting a `bytes` variable of length 20 uses about 420 gas.

Hope this helps

Comment: Getting an error in Remix: TypeError: Return argument type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256

Comment: Can you show me your code?, this works for me well in remix, I put the whole code so you can just copy and paste it. Let me know

Comment: Oh there you go. I think your first post had the return value as "b". This works. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Slicing an uint out of bytes using inline assembly

```
function sliceUint(bytes bs, uint start)
    internal pure
    returns (uint)
{
    require(bs.length >= start + 32, "slicing out of range");
    uint x;
    assembly {
        x := mload(add(bs, add(0x20, start)))
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Gas efficient solution here

Answer (score 6):

A fully working modern solution can be found in this [repository](https://github.com/GNSPS/solidity-bytes-utils/blob/6458fb2780a3092bc756e737f246be1de6d3d362/contracts/BytesLib.sol#L374-L383), authored by ConsenSys:

```
function toUint256(bytes memory _bytes, uint256 _start) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(_bytes.length >= _start + 32, "toUint256_outOfBounds");
    uint256 tempUint;

    assembly {
        tempUint := mload(add(add(_bytes, 0x20), _start))
    }

    return tempUint;
}
```

The accepted answer is not working in Solidity ^0.5 anymore; it produces a type conversion error.

Comment: nice nice nice!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the bytes length(for instance address has 20 bytes), you can convert by casting

```
uint256 time = uint160(bytes20(0x2E4e72EDC83053F8ADE4a525191Ba7aBA086c067));
```

Comment: Any risk for this?

Comment: I don't see any risk. uint160 is 20 bytes long. And uint256 fits uint160.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use byte-wise computation! it's very inefficient! The latest solidity allow you to do this:

To convert a general `byte memory` to uint:

```
function bytesToUint(bytes memory b) internal pure virtual returns (uint256) {
    require(b.length <= 32, "Bytes length exceeds 32.");
    return abi.decode(abi.encodePacked(new bytes(32 - b.length), b), (uint256));
}
```

If you're unpacking a big `bytes calldata` (you know exactly how many bytes each slice has), you can also just cast it through `bytesX`  as follow:

```
function decodeCompressedCalldata(bytes calldata compressed) internal {
    // convert to uint
    uint64 expiry = uint64(bytes8(compressed[0:8]));

    // convert to uint -> int
    int a = int80(uint80(bytes10(compressed[8:18])));
}
```